# Cloudera Hue - Hive Editor error for loading JSON to HIVE error on JAR file

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh

I am running a HIVE query using the HUE Editor from Cloudera Distribution 
It is giving an error on not able to find the JAR file even if I see the JAR file 
I did two things:

1. Used a JAR file in the /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars file directory that is available
2. Run the query
3. Failed with error of 
   `"Error while processing statement: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/hive-hcatalog-core-1.1.0-cdh5-4-7.jar does not exist"`

The jar file exists in that directory according to the command :

```
[jars]$ pwd
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars
[jars]$ ls -ltr hive-hcatalog*

    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  54875 Sep 17  2015 hive-hcatalog-streaming-1.1.0-cdh5.4.7.jar
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51534 Sep 17  2015 hive-hcatalog-server-extensions-1.1.0-cdh5.4.7.jar
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51359 Sep 17  2015 hive-hcatalog-pig-adapter-1.1.0-cdh5.4.7.jar
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 253955 Sep 17  2015 hive-hcatalog-core-1.1.0-cdh5.4.7.jar
```

SECOND OPTION :
1. I downloaded another JsonSerDe and loaded it in my home directory

```
json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

2. Changed the ADD command 
3. Still same error

This is being run using the following :
1. Cloudera Distribution 5.4.7
2. HUE EDITOR

Here is the script to create the HIVE table:

```
ADD JAR /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/hive-hcatalog-core-1.1.0-cdh5-4-7.jar;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aacoe.BROKERAGE_EVENTS;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aacoe.BROKERAGE_EVENTS (
     evt struct<evtTypCd    string ,
     evtCd  string ,
     evtDscTe   string ,
     evtLclTs   string ,
     evtLclTmZnNa   string ,
     evtUtcTcfTs    string ,
     evtUtcTcfQy    string ,
     smtNr  string ,
     busLinDscTe    string ,
     smtDcvDt   string ,
     dclUidNr   string ,
     mltPrfOfDelNa  string ,
     mltDelOdrNr    string ,
     mltSmtConNr    string ,
     xcpRsnCd   string ,
     xcpRsnDscTe    string ,
     xcpRlvCd   string ,
     xcpRlvDscTe    string ,
     xcpRlvLclTs    string ,
     xcpRlvLclTmZnNa    string ,
     xcpRlvUtcTcfTs     string ,
     xcpRlvUtcTcfQy     string ,
     xcpCtmDspCd    string ,
     rpnInfSrcCrtUtcTcfTs   string ,
     rpnInfSrcCrtUtcTcfQy   string ,
     rpnInfSrcCrtLclTs  string ,
     rpnInfSrcCrtLclTmZnNa  string ,
     rpnEntLinNr    string ,
     rpnGovAcoTe    string ,
     rpnEntLvlSts   string ,
     rpnLinLvlSts   string ,
     loc array<struct<
         adLin1Te   string ,
         adLin2Te   string ,
         adLin3Te   string ,
         adMunNa    string ,
         adPslCd    string ,
         adCnySdvCd     string ,
         adXcpDclPorCd  string ,
         ogzNr  string ,
         adCnyCd :      string ,
         >>>
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'

    load data local inpath '/data/5/xxxxxx/subject/testdata/BAS/EVENTS/' into table aacoe.BROKERAGE_EVENTS;
```

Comment: Ever find a solution?  I'm having same problem in CDH 5.12.x